# How can I make a buttons from a Layout in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I have buttons what I made with "LinearLayout" but when I want to made them clickable and so that it goes to another activity. I understand, that I need to change from "LinearLayout" to "ImageButton" because I want to make a beautiful app [what I want it looks like][1], but when I launch it, it stops working. What can I do to repair that? Thank you in advance for your help and sorry for my bad english. :(

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/header_background"
        android:padding="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textHello"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:text="@string/hello"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textUsername"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:text="@string/vassili"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textHello"
            tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageMenu"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textHello"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textHello"
            app:tint="@color/colorWhite"
            tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layoutHeader"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-96dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutGoal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_background_icons"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H, 1:1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/layoutTraining"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/notepad" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/goals"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutTraining"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_background_icons"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H, 1:1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/layoutGoal"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/dumbbell" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/Trainings"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutWater"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_background_icons"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H, 1:1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/layoutTraining"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layoutGoal"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/bottle" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/Water"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutStepCounter"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_background_icons"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H, 1:1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/layoutGoal"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layoutTraining"
                tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/walk" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/step_counter"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdW6v.png
```

Comment: Please, when asking about errors/crash, share the error log with us, so we'll be able to help. Log error can be found on "logcat" and "run" tab.

Answer (score 0):

May you need to change  constraintlayout  to LinearLayout and if you want click be on image  add id to imageview

Answer (score 0):

For this type of layout you need to make your LinearLayout clickable
For example:

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutGoals;
```

then in you onCreate do findViewById and set its clickListener

```
linearLayoutGoals = findViewById(R.id.layoutGoal);
linearLayoutGoals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //DO YOUR CODE
        }
    });
```